# Activity state only restored when launched from Eclipse

Tags: android, android-activity

I have the problem that the state of my activity gets only restored (after killing or put to background) if I launch the App via the Eclipse Run menu.
If I export the App and put it manually on the (same) device, the state gets not restored when I kill and restart the App.
I assume I overlook something. Can anyone tell me what? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be an old thread, but this may help others.
This is a known defect
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18338
Installing and launching app from eclipse, or launching from apps menu will restore the state, but if we are installing the app manually (by copying to SD card etc.) and launch directly will not restore the sate.

Answer (score 0):

The android system automatically remembers the state when you close the app. You specifically have to kill it from Settings -> Applications -> Your app -> Kill

Comment: Yeah, I know. The problem is that the system does that only when I launch the app using eclipse. In other cases, the state is _not_ remembered. And that is the problem.